# Soap request in flutter

Tags: flutter, soap, http-status-code-400

I am trying to send a soap request to http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx in flutter to add 2 number

```
ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  var request="""
                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                      <soap:Body>
                        <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                          <intA>1</intA>
                          <intB>2</intB>
                        </Add>
                      </soap:Body>
                    </soap:Envelope>
                  """;
                  http.Response response =
                      await http.post(
                        Uri.parse('http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx'),
                        headers: {
                          "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                          "Host": "www.dneonline.com",
                          "Content-Length": request.length.toString(),
                          "SOAPAction": "http://tempuri.org/Add"
                        },
                        body: request
                      );
                  print(response.body);
                },
                child: new Text("Calculate"),
              )
```

But I am getting an error

Error: XMLHttpRequest error.

```
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 910:28                get current
```

packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 69:22

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1685:54                                              runUnary

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 159:18                                        handleValue

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 766:44                                        handleValueCallback

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 795:13                                        _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 592:7                                         [_complete]

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1288:7

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 334:14  _checkAndCall

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 339:39  dcall

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37301:58

```
at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:65501/dart_sdk.js:5080:12)

at Function._throw (http://localhost:65501/dart_sdk.js:20337:18)

at Function.throwWithStackTrace (http://localhost:65501/dart_sdk.js:20334:18)

at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:65501/dart_sdk.js:40851:18)

at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:65501/dart_sdk.js:40708:13)

at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:65501/dart_sdk.js:40714:13)

at http://localhost:65501/dart_sdk.js:36191:9
```

I am using and android studio

http: ^0.13.4

xml: ^5.3.1

Anyone please help

Edit:

Update

I was trying in web and was getting cors issue.
Now I am trying in android and I am getting an 400 StatusCode

[Statuscode and body image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vewK.png)

SoapUI OUTPUT

[soapui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkNJ8.png)

Comment: Seems to be CORS issue. are you runing on Web  ?

Comment: Yes it is running in web, let me check

Comment: CORS issue will be at  Server side

Comment: Now I am getting no error but I have no data. I am using android phone now

Comment: Do you have internet permission in manifest file of android folder ?

Comment: Yes I re-checked everything

Comment: can you share exception what exactly are you getting on  android ?

Comment: I am now getting an 400 error. Thanks till now for your help

Comment: can you share that 400 error . i mean response body 
of it

Comment: I added the image to the main question

Comment: Seems to be you have authorization error. check this for SOAP request : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53505624/soap-request-in-flutter-dart

Comment: But In SoapUI no authorization was required SoapUI output in main question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here you can check this. its working for me

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';



  _hitApi() async {
    
       var requestBody ='''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
        <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
          <intA>2</intA>
          <intB>4</intB>
        </Add>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>''';
    
    
       Response response = await post(
         Uri.parse('http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx'),
         headers: {
           'content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
           'SOAPAction': 'http://tempuri.org/Add',
            'Host': 'www.dneonline.com',
         },
         body: utf8.encode(requestBody),
        
       );
    
    
       print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
       print("Response body: ${response.body}");
     }
```

And here is response :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><AddResponse
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><AddResult>6</AddResult></AddResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: It works, but was the problem??

Comment: "Content-Length": request.length.toString(), is not rquired in headers

Comment: Thanks I got it working!!